# Modx site transfer problems. Maps and sliders not working

Tags: php, jquery, modx, modx-revolution

When **modx** site is transfered from one pc to another, map `iframe` and sliders are not working.... I am dealing with **Modx Revolution CMS** for the first time. Can you please describe the correct steps for transferring modx site from localhost to the live server?

Comment: Which cms you using? Modx revolution or modx evolution? First determine, and only then ask.

Comment: Modx Revolution 2.5.1

Answer (score 0):

https://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/administering-your-site/moving-your-site-to-a-new-server - all steps perfectly described in the official documentation.